# OpenMP offloading

Tags: gpu, openmp, nvidia, offloading

I have an array of struct A that has arrays and int variables. How can I map them to the target

```
Strcut A{
    int **a;
    int *x;
    int *y;  
    int ny;
    int nx;
}A;
A arrayA = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A)*MaxSize);
for(int i=0; i<MaxSize; i++){
    arrayA[i].a = (int**)(malloc(sizeof(int*)*arrayA[i].nx);
    for(int j=0; j< arrayA[i].nx; j++)
       arrayA[i].a[j] = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*arrayA[i].ny); 
    arrayA[i].x = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*arrayA[i].ny);
    arrayA[i].y = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*arrayA[i].ny);
}
#pragma omp target data map(from:arrayA[i].y) map(to:arrayA[i].x,arrayA[i].a, arrayA[i].ny,arrayA[i].nx)
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
 for(i=0;i<MaxSize; i++){
    methodA(arrayA[i].x,arrayA[i].a, arrayA[i].ny,arrayA[i].nx, arrayA[i].y);
}
```

However, this does not work. What is the best way to pass the arrayA?

I am using gcc 8.3

Comment: Can you be more specific with your statement "this does not work"? What exactly is not working?

Comment: The error is error: expected ‘)’ before ‘.’ token
 #pragma omp target data map(tofrom:dataCPU[i].n,

Answer (score 0):

Simply using

```
map(tofrom:arrayA)
```

should do the trick.

If this doesn't work please supply us with the errors you receive.

Do you have the target's software installed correctly (nvcc - Nvidia compiler)? Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917356/how-to-verify-cuda-installation-in-16-04) question to ensure that it is set up. If not, download the toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604).

EDIT:

The code below compiled:

```
typedef struct{
    int **a;
    int *x;
    int *y;  
    int ny;
    int nx;
} A;
A *arrayA = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A) * maxSize);
for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++){
    arrayA[i].a = (int**)(malloc(sizeof(int*)*arrayA[i].nx));
    for(int j=0; j< arrayA[i].nx; j++)
        arrayA[i].a[j] = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*arrayA[i].ny)); 
    arrayA[i].x = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*arrayA[i].ny));
    arrayA[i].y = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)*arrayA[i].ny));
}
#pragma omp target data map(tofrom:arrayA)
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
for(int i=0;i<maxSize; i++){
    methodA(arrayA[i].x,arrayA[i].a, arrayA[i].ny,arrayA[i].nx, arrayA[i].y);
}
```

Comment: The error is expected ‘)’ before ‘.’ token
 #pragma omp target data map(tofrom:arrayA[i].n

Comment: Oh right, you're supposed to only give the reference to the array. Thus `map(tofrom:arrayA)`.

Comment: It did compile, but it does not work correctly in the device. It gave this error:   libgomp: cuCtxSynchronize error: an illegal memory access was encountered

libgomp: cuMemFreeHost error: an illegal memory access was encountered